# How to return "Empty" where a query returns empty cells Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two columns. The first one contains names and the second some numbers. I am perfoming a query on the two columns but some of the cells in the second columns will not contain any value. I need to return "Empty" in those cells but I seem not to be able to with my formula. When I add ISBLANK to the query it throws an error.

My query `=query($A$1:$B$20, "select A, B where (B <=80)")`

Link to my spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12gDxvNONKYxqAPJa6FPGJMXkNv6wlXgHEMNjCg-Iuco/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(QUERY(A1:B, "where B <=80 and A is not null")="", 
        "Empty", QUERY(A1:B, "where B <=80")))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A, ""&IF((A2:A<>"")*(B2:B=""), "Empty", B2:B), B2:B},
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col2='Empty' or Col3<=80", 0))
```

[image: 0]